# Problem with the Bitmap to take screenshots

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, screenshot, android-mediaprojection

1. I have this line of code for taking screenshots I take the screenshot but somethimes the image only show a white backgroud and doesn't show the full color of the image how can I solve this?
2. Postdata I have other question with the fullcode [Problem with taking screenshots with the media projection android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129214/problem-with-taking-screenshots-with-the-media-projection-android-studio) and I discover that the problem happened with this line of code.

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth+rowPadding/pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the compression of your image.

[Check out the link below](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config)

Comment: The compression was correct the main problem in that code was one of the methods thank you very much for trying to help me